# What strategy to use in Java for hierarchical reentrant read/write locking?

Tags: java, locking, hierarchical, reentrancy, readwritelock

I'm looking for en efficient system to have a series of read/write locks organized hierarchically to manage access to hierarchically organized resources. If a subtree is locked for write, then no other lock should be able to be obtained in the whole subtree until it is released; similarly, a write lock in a subtree should prevent locking in a parent.

Here are the ideas I was contemplating:

- **Use the [Apache Commons Transaction](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/)**. Unforunately, the project hasn't been updated since March 2008 and has unofficially been terminated. Some API docs seemed to indicate that the version to come (1.3 or 2.0) would include [some kind of hierarchical locking](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/apidocs/org/apache/commons/transaction/locking/HierarchicalLockManager.html), but the sources are nowhere to be found and it seems we can't access their SVN repository any more.
- **Use a series of [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`s](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)**, which I would organize hierarchically. I'm no concurrency expert, and I'm a bit afraid to do that on my own. Preliminary thoughts seemed to indicate that even before I can try to lock a subtree, I'd have to use an outer lock on the whole structure managing the `ReentrantReadWriteLock`s itself — so that even for *releasing a lock* I'd have to use the outer lock…
- **Use classes from [`java.util.concurrent`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)** to implement my hierarchical lock in a more efficient way than I could do with a series of `ReentrantReadWriteLock`s.

I'm ready to go down that last road, but I was surprised not to find any exiting library that would solve this problem better. So:

- Have I missed some obvious solution?
- Or is this problem just especially hard to solve properly?

Comment: Stay away from `atomic`, it is ridiculously subtle to correctly understand and implement.

Comment: Your second solution seems the right one.  You need the get a global lock when you want to lock a node such that you can check that none of the children of that node is locked, and also that none of its parent is locked.

Comment: By the way, Commons Transaction is [available](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/download_transaction.cgi), but I have no idea if it is useful to you.

Comment: @toto Thanks for commenting on my approach. Yes, version 1.2 is available, but does not include the hierarchical lock stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I understood well your question, as you say that when you lock a subtree for write, the whole structure is locked.
So, the simple solution is to have one RW lock for the whole structure.

By the way, `java.util.concurrent.atomic` won't help you more than a tree of RW locks.

---

If you want to be able locking siblings independly, you may go with the second solution (a tree of locks where each node has a reference to its parent).

Locking a node would be locking it using its write lock and locking every parent using read locks.
A parent cannot be locked while a child is, because you cannot acquire its write lock as locking a child already acquired the read lock.
Locking a child is only permitted if no other thread has write-locked any parent.

The lock described above is an exclusive lock.
*(another name for read-write locks is shared-exclusive locks)*

To add shared locks, each node also needs an atomic integer indicating:
if it's positive, the number of indirect write-locked children; if it's negative the number of times the node has been read-locked.
Also, the node and its parents will be read locked to avoid new write locks being acquired on parents.

The pseudo-code:

```
Node {
    // fields
    parent: Node
    lock: RWLock
    count: AtomicInteger
}

public boolean trylocktree(node: Node, exclusive: boolean) {
    if (exclusive) {
        return trylocktree_ex(node, true);
    } else {
        return trylocktree_sh(node);
    }
}
private boolean switch_count(i: AtomicInteger, diff: int) {
    // adds diff to i if the sign of i is the same as the sign of diff
    while (true) {
        int v = i.get();
        if (diff > 0 ? v < 0 : v > 0)
            return false;
        if (i.compareAndSet(v, v + diff))
            return true;
    }
}
private boolean trylocktree_ex(node: Node, writing: boolean) {
    // check if a node is read-locked
    if (!switch_count(node.count, 1))
        return false;
    // lock using the lock type passed as an arg
    if (!node.lock(writing).trylock()) {
        node.count--;
        return false;
    }
    // read-lock every parent
    if (!trylocktree_ex(node.parent, false)) {
        node.count--
        node.lock(writing).unlock();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean trylocktree_sh(node: Node) {
    // mark as shared-locked subtree
    if (!switch_count(node.count, -1))
        return false;
    // get shared-lock on parents
    if (!readlock_recursively(node)) {
        node.count++;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
private boolean readlock_recursively(node: Node) {
    if (!node.lock(false).trylock())
        return false;
    if (!readlock_recursively(node.parent)) {
        node.lock(false).unlock();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If any lock couldn't be acquired, then you unlock what you have locked and retry later (you can use a global condition variable, a timeout, etc to achieve this).

**EDIT:** added code to read-lock/write-lock a tree

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. I'm not sure that it is enough to read-lock the parents if I write-lock a child, because someone may then want to read-lock the parent itself and expect consistent reading of all children), and that wouldn't work because the write-locked child would be updated at the same time...

Comment: The lock I described here is an implementation of a reentrant lock for such a structure, not a read-write lock. I'm working on a read/write lock solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Still: it seems that with your implementation, if I write-lock a child, another thread can still read-lock the parent, which is unfortunate. Looks like we need another counter: number of write-locked descendants or something like that.

Comment: If a child is write-locked, it holds also read-locks for every parent and `count` of every parent is positive. Since read-locking needs to change the `count` to a negative value, if `count` is already strictly positive, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I will go for your own solution and take the algorithm given by Apache [Apache Commons Transaction Algorithm](http://commons.apache.org/transaction/locks/deadlock.html) as starting point.
You can use a ReentrantReadWriteLock although usually this lock fits better the pattern of one producer-many readers case which may not be what you are looking for. It seems your lock is more like a regular reentrant mutex lock.